# grep specific string from command output

Tags: php, linux, grep

I analyze stream from multicast address. Output of the command looks like this:

```
...
Sep 03 19:06:45: INFO: Bitrate: 8241 Kbit/s
Sep 03 19:06:45: ERROR: Scrambled: 250=4792 251=132 252=132 253=263
...
```

I need get value after **Bitrate:** [ 8241 ] and set frist variable in php script, and after **Scrambled:** only before "=" [250,251,252,253] for second variable.
Example `$var1=8241; $var2=250,251,252,253`. I found how `grep -oP '(?<=Bitrate: )[0-9]+'` so I get "8241" but i need both variables i one step.

Comment: Is the 'scrambled' line always a follow-up to the 'bitrate' line? Is it possible there are multiple different lines between them? Or is it you just want 1 regex that's capable of handle both lines separately?

Answer (score 1):

It would be problematic for you to grep the needed values into the 2 variables simultaneously.

So here's a complete ***php*** solution (using `shell_exec` function to call ***awk*** script):

```
<?php

$command = 'yourcommand | awk \'/Bitrate/{ printf "%d ", $6 }/Scrambled/{ for(i=6;i<=NF;i++)' 
                           . 'printf "%d ",substr($i,1,index($i,"=")) }\' 
';
$result = trim(shell_exec($command));
if ($result) {
    $arr = explode(" ", $result);
    $bitrate = $arr[0];
    $scrambled = array_slice($arr, 1);
}

print_r('bitrate: ' . $bitrate . PHP_EOL);
print_r('scrambled: ');
print_r($scrambled);
```

Formatted output:

```
bitrate: 8241
scrambled: Array
(
    [0] => 250
    [1] => 251
    [2] => 252
    [3] => 253
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question this fast! 
I understand logik, but, I not using file. What I need i **command analyze | awk**, i traynig with this code but not result. It would be easier for me to use one variable with a specific separator. Example result **8241#250,251,252,253**

Comment: @Zeljko, at start, run `your command | myawk (without filename)` in shell and make sure that it return the result

Comment: `$command = 'timeout 2 /my_src/astra/./astra --analyze udp://p5p1.4@239.1.1.231:22231 | awk \'/Bitrate/{ printf "%d ", $6 }/Scrambled/{ for(i=6;i<=NF;i++)' 
                           . 'printf "%d ",substr($i,1,index($i,"=")) }\' 
';` This return `[log] failed to write to the stdout [Broken pipe]`. Source command return (all lines) https://pastebin.com/zjWKQsaD

Comment: @Zeljko, of course, your command seems to work with buffered output and timeout, it's not a static stream, so you are getting that error

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest Ok, but with grep i get correct result `timeout 2 /my_src/astra/./astra --analyze $url | grep -oP '(?<=Bitrate: )[0-9]+'`  Result is [8241]. The only thing that is still needed is value on Scrambled line if exists :) Thank you in any case.

Comment: @Zeljko, try the following `timeout 2 /my_src/astra/./astra --analyze $url | | grep -Po '.*(Bitrate|Scrambled):\K.*'` . It should return `8241 Kbit/s
 250=4792 251=132 252=132 253=263`

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest i'ts correct! I get result `8241 Kbit/s 250=4792 251=132 252=132 253=263` Also the command `awk -F'[[:space:]=]' '/Bitrate/||/Scrambled/{print $6}'` return 8241 250 but only frist value (250) on Scrambled line.